# ffmpeg Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description matches no streams for muted audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I get an error message 'Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description' for a video with muted audio. How can I detect such videos which I cannot specify their audio stream?

The command : '`ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=2:a=2[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" joined.mp4`'

Output : '`Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description  [0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=2:a=2[v][a] matches no streams.`'

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'background.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2021-11-19T07:07:21.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:14.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1140 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1008 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr,
15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-11-19T07:07:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/18/2021.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-11-19T07:07:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/18/2021.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Comment: Please post the full command and the full output of the command

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: The full output of the command (the one printed in the terminal) is still not present. In particular we can't see anything related to the file `video.mp4`

Comment: That said you are coding `v=2:a=2`in the concat filter, meaning that you are expecting 2 video streams and 2 audio streams in the input files, while at least `background.mp4` contains only one of each.